# Can I add extra data to an oraclize query so that I can use it in the callback function?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, oracles

I would like to be able to use certain data in the callback of an oraclize query that I want to pass in when creating the oraclize query.

Say I have the following function in a contract:

```
function updateExchangeRate(uint delay, uint userId){
    oraclize_query(delay, "URL", "json(https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD).USD");
    // have the userId value be usable in the oraclize callback function
  }
```

Is it possible to add data to that query than can be used in the callback function? I want to pass in a userId every time I make an oraclize query that I can then use in the callback function.

Is that possible?

Comment: You get a request ID back so can't you store that in a mapping with the user ID?

Comment: Thomas from Oraclize here, I confirm that the @EdmundEdgar hint is the right way to go!

Comment: @ThomasBertani how do you get the request id when you make the request to store at that point?

Comment: Figured it out. Just had to take a quick look at the docs. The request itself returns the id of the request.

Comment: @Pabi yes indeed! http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-integration-the-query-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the query ID that comes back from the request and then store that as a mapping with the user ID. Here is the section in the docs (the link in the comments isn't working): http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start-the-query-id.

```
bytes32 queryId = oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP).rates.GBP");
```